# How to navigate between Objectvie c view to swift view in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

i just started to write the swift code for IOS, I created a swift UIViewController in existing Objective-C project, the navigation between Objective-C to swift working fine, but if I cannot do the Swift to Objective-C . is there any way to solve this, give me some URLs for this kind of documentation. :(

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Hi @EnricoSusatyo, i am working on Objective-C project right now, i am planing to move this to swift one by one, so any new page i am planing to create in swift UIView controller . in that i am not clear in the navigating between controllers. now i need a solution to navigate between swift and Objective view controllers .

Comment: Can you be more specific? What isn't working?

Comment: @AnnaDickinson, Enrico Susatyo , i just find out how to do that, thank you guys :)

Comment: hi prakash i am newbie to swift can u let me know how u have implemented from swift to objective c

Comment: I just add the header reference #import "projectname-Swift.h"
Then we can use normal redirection methods to navigate . meaning it give you like ObjC object